# Python class overwrites previous initialisation, instead of making new ones

Tags: python, class, init

To be honest I don't even know how to call this error.

```
def create_vimeo_objects_details_DTO_thumbnail(number=5): 
    max_widths = []
    test_thumbnail = []
    for i in range(number):
        new_width = randint(0,2540)
        max_widths.append(new_width)
        dto_thumbnail = {
            'Thumbnail' : {
                'link' : '',
                'width' : new_width
            }
        }
        test_thumbnail = test_thumbnail + [VimeoObjectDetailsDTO(dto_thumbnail).Thumbnail]
    print('test thumbnail: ', [a.width for a in test_thumbnail])
```

`dto_thumbnail` is part of the class which has to be initiated from request (dictionary)

```
class VimeoObjectDetailsDTO:

    files = []
    pictures = None
    duration = None

    class FileDto:
        width = None
        height = None
        link = ''
        quality = ''

    class Pictures:
        sizes = []

    class Thumbnail:
        width = None
        link = ''

    def __init__(self, response):
        if 'files' in response: self.files = response['files']
        if 'pictures' in response: self.pictures = response['pictures']
        if 'duration' in response: self.duration = response['duration']
        if 'FileDto' in response:
            if 'width' in response['FileDto']: self.FileDto.width = response['FileDto']['width']
            if 'link' in response['FileDto']: self.FileDto.link = response['FileDto']['link']
            if 'height' in response['FileDto']: self.FileDto.height = response['FileDto']['height']
            if 'quality' in response['FileDto']: self.FileDto.quality = response['FileDto']['quality']
        if 'Pictures' in response:
            if 'sizes' in response['Pictures']: self.Pictures.sizes = response['Pictures']['sizes']
        if 'Thumbnail' in response:
            if 'width' in response['Thumbnail']: self.Thumbnail.width = response['Thumbnail']['width']
            if 'link' in response['Thumbnail']: self.Thumbnail.link = response['Thumbnail']['link']
```

when I execute this function, I get for example:

```
test thumbnail:  [1893, 1893, 1893, 1893, 1893]
```

but when I print `max_widths` I get proper - different numbers

How can I make, this function return/print proper `VimeoObjectDetailsDTO.Thumbnails` ? (it does not matter if I use "+" or append)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only one `Thumbnail` object common to all instances of your classes, as it is a class attribute. Therefore, whenever you mutate `self.Thumbnail`, you act on the same object.

There are not so many legitimate uses for inner classes, and this is certainly not a justified one. Furthermore, these classes don't have any methods, they could maybe be dicts, or even not exist at all, like `Pictures`.

Anyway, whatever you do, you want to have instance attributes, not class attributes, so you should create them in `__init__`.